# What do you do if your question was closed and you disagree?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28401501/running-apache-storm-0-10-on-windows) and 5 reviewers decided to close it, unanimously. The reason:

> Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools

I was shocked because of the number of reviewers who all seem to agree while I vehemently disagree. And also, the fact that some of these reviewers have 40k points on SO suggested to me that they know SO better than me.

I then asked the same question in the Apache Storm forum and the answer was as simple as the trunk of the library is not stable. The recommendation is to use a release.

So, I would love a broader audience to help me understand why this question does not belong on SO. Because AFAIK, this is a software development/release I was dealing with.

Edit: Searching on SO, I found such questions as "can SOLR be run on Azure" or "SOLR error exception issue" or "Verify version of rabbitmq", or "RabbitMQ management" that were NOT cloised. How are they any more development than not being able to run Apache Storm.

Comment: What to do?  Reevaluate your expectations.  That question is off-topic.

Comment: reviewers are not gods,  if one reviewer consider (in his opinion) a question off-topic the other just follows him. This is typical to someone unable to answer a question, but want to show that he as understand it and then close enough to consider it to be off-topic. You have to deal with this kind of people here

Comment: @albanx that is a slightly jaded view. I hope it is only a minority who act that way. "Skip" is a fine option in the review queue. It is the humbler choice, I agree.

Comment: The fact that you found other off-topic questions that are not closed does not make your question less off-topic.

Comment: @albanx _"other just follows him [...] this is typical to someone unable to answer a question"_ - please don't make such indefensible claims. Do you seriously think all or a lot of close votes are cast by clueless users?

Comment: @CodeCaster no I do not think, it's a fact, and the question above prove it (again). I read it and I do not see any offtopic argument there. Please do not make SO a flame-war site, like you and some other behave here instead in just helping community (for what SO was design initially)

Comment: @albanx thanks for accusing me of that. Can you show me where I am starting a flamewar?

Comment: @CodeCaster I do not want to accuse you, but you commented my comment with "please don't make such indefensible claims" is the start of a flame

Comment: @albanx uhm, no, your first comment, claiming _"most reviewers just flag to close a question if they are unable to answer it"_ is a poor attempt to troll. There you are making a false claim you cannot possibly defend, which is what I called you out on.

Comment: Existence of a previous question does not automatically make a similar question on-topic here. Guidelines change over time, and new [se] sites are added. The only thing relevant are the guidelines that are in effect today, and your question is off-topic according to the current guidelines IMO as well. It's a server configuration issue, not a programming issue. Programming relates to source code, and programmers tools refers to tools commonly used by programmers (IDEs, libraries, APIs, etc.), and your question is about none of those things.

Comment: @albanx: Your comment is in fact indefensible, unless you can absolutely prove that a large percentage of the close votes are a case of people that just *follow* other reviewers , and unless you have **actual evidence** that proves that *this is typical to someone unable to answer a question*. Can you **document** (defend) both of those statements with actual **evidence**? If not, your statement is indefensible, and there's no flaming involved in pointing that out. Wildly inaccurate or false statements don't benefit anyone here. In other words, if you can't provide evidence, it's not true.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Yep. Fixed. Thanks for pointing out the mistake, and my apologies for grabbing the wrong name out of the thread - I was actually agreeing with your position :).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many of the answers here seem to be addressing whether the specific question you posted as the example here, so I'm going to take a stab at the bigger question you asked in this post which was what to do generally when you think a question was incorrectly closed.

Generally speaking, if a question you've posted has been closed and you think that the closure was a mistake, what you should be doing is to make sure that you fully understand the stated reason for closure. It's possible that your feeling is based on a misunderstanding of what is on-topic for Stack Overflow and a review of the rules will clear that up.

Next, if you feel that you've verified what's on topic and you still think your question is being misunderstood, you should consider if there's something about your question that would cause a reader to misinterpret your intent in a way that would seem off-topic. If so, you should edit the question to reduce that risk, and explain clearly in the comments why you think your question does not fit the stated close reason.

Finally, if you've done that, you should be open to the feedback you're getting. If you've truly revised or clarified the question, it's possible that your question will be reopened. However, it's also possible that it won't, if it is still fundamentally off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you still feel unclear as to why the question is closed, you can ask for feedback on it on Meta using the [specific-question] tag, where you'll likely get answers similar to those provided by others on this question.

Answer (score 32):

Your argument for considering it on-topic boils down to:

> All software is the result of programming, therefore using the software is about programming.

And everyone else disagrees with your redefinition of "about programming".

When there is a dispute about the meaning of a term used in the site rules, the opinion that matters is "original intent".  Focus on the intent of the rule rather than its verbiage.  In this case, the architects of Stack Overflow intended not to permit questions about usage of a compiled program.

Comment: Agree. Imagine the torrent of questions that would flood SO if questions like "I was trying to build open-source-XYZ and it failed". They're off topic for a reason. This is a place of code.

Comment: @cmroanirgo: That's actually a different fight.  Difference between "I tried to build XYZ and the build failed" vs "I build XYZ and it isn't doing what I want".

Comment: I sort of understand "everybody else" perspective. Though, I still disagree. If it was about building MySQL, then yes, this would make sense. But I want to believe that Apache Storm is built primarily for development purposes. Imagine a developer not being able to run Apache commons library examples or test cases, would you classify this as off topic on SO?. Anyway, my takeaway is to go directly to the respective forums. Thanks everybody.

Comment: What in SO's help section gives you the idea that SO is the ONLY community? Have you looked at other communities on StackExchange - or elsewhere?

Comment: @Klaus: "I want to believe that Apache Storm is built primarily for development purposes"  It doesn't matter what other people use it for.  Is this problem related to code you wrote, or not?  If you are developing against the Apache Storm library, and it is your code that's exiting early, then the question would be on-topic... but unless you explain the relationship between your code and Storm, it would be closed as unclear.

Answer (score 9):

How to build a particular tool isn't on topic here.  How to use it might be.

The fact that a question has an answer, even an easy answer, has no bearing on whether it's appropriate for SO.  Clearly the question is on-topic for the Apache Storm forum, and it's no surprise that you got an answer there.

Comment: Building tools are certainly on-topic here, the OP however isn't building anything, he's trying to **run** something.

Comment: @remyabel He's trying to run something he built.  Building from a release fixes his problem, so it's a build issue.  I don't agree that instructions to build a particular release of any software package is on-topic.  In the case that the information in an answer is helpful, it will be out-of-date very quickly.

Answer (score 8):

I would not take it personally. A question is closed when it "doesn't look like the kinds of questions we answer here". What that means changes over time and is driven by people who spent the most time here - which gives them a certain right to speak up.

The idea behind closing questions is that we would like each question to get exposure to an audience most likely to be able to give a useful answer. Questions have a very short half life on the front page of SO - chances that your question is seen by the right person increase when it is posted on the most relevant forum.

If there is one thing that closers of a question like this ought to do, it is recommending that the question be moved to another site. It is an option in the "off topic" category of close reasons. But it does require a few more keystrokes by the moderator (especially if the recommended site isn't one of the "standard choices")

Comment: why not add then a move to right section button?

Comment: That button exists... But you have to type the name of the "right section". And if you are not sure it is easier to simply close it and let the OP figure it out. Having figured out the correct site you can flag the question for moderator attention and request the move.

Comment: no it does not exits , it just a notice where the question should be

Comment: Well yes only the diamond moderators can actually move the question (and they do if you ask them)

Comment: yes but it is useless, they mark question as off-topic but they do not move it to the right section. at most they just downvote it

Comment: @albanx: The poster has to make sure he posts to the right site. And migrations have quite a high rejection-rate, even for the common targets where there is a path. Also, there is not always a right site on SE, and the question is often of insufficient quality for any SE site anyway.

Comment: @Deduplicator the poster needs helps, does not need criticism and flame, loosing time over time to convince people that he does not intended to do such a big mistake posting in the wrong (approximate) section (because he does'nt posted a programming question in the food & drink section)